# Regular Expression not considering . while doing pattern test in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Below is the code to check the expression. It will check for start for string, after space and after @ .

```
  var mail1 = "john.ga@gmail.com";
var mail2  = "john_wb@gmail.com";

var searchData = "john.";

var pattern1 = new RegExp("(?:^|[\\s\@])"+searchData, "i");
if(pattern1.test(mail1)){
   console.log("matched is:::"+mail1.match(pattern1));
}
 if(pattern1.test(mail2)){
   console.log("matched is:::"+mail2.match(pattern1));
}
```

It should not match mail2. but its not considering "." and matching the mail2 also.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LQg7W/2319/

but when i give "searchData" variable as "john_" , it will search correctly.
Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LQg7W/2320/

How to resolve this issue.

Comment: `@` doesn't need to be escaped

Comment: @ThiefMaster : Ah Thanks For that. But any help in resolving "." issue :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.` is a match all character in regex so, you need to escape it by

```
var pattern1 = new RegExp("(?:^|[\\s\@])"+searchData.replace(/\./g, '\\.'), "i");
```

Updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LQg7W/2321/)

Comment: Thanks Alot. Saved my Time. I know that "." matches all characters. I tried to escape it in differet way but it didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

Dot matches all. In regex, a dot is a wildcard that matches any character, so it matches your literal dot in `john.ga@gmail.com`, but it matches the underscore in `john_wb@gmail.com` just as easily.

To match a literal dot, you need to escape it with a backslash, like so `\.`. Also, there are other characters that have special meanings. Just concatenating the searchData to your pattern can leave you with all kinds of unescaped special characters that could even render your expression invalid, causing an error, or possibly create a *very* slow match that will take forever.
If there's no library function in JavaScript to escape all special characters, you should create one yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The dot in searchData is not escaped, so it matches any character.

You need to escape it :

```
var searchData = "john\.";
```

If you need a more generic way to escape your search pattern, you might find this question useful : [Is there a RegExp.escape function in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript)